# How can i hide a text in Html using JavaScript if the window width is lower than a given value and show it if it's greater than the value

Tags: javascript, html

I tried the `window.screen.width` methode, but it seems that the script runs **only one time** (when the page loads), **i am looking for a methode to use so the code can be always running**.

 Here's my **JavaScript** code:

```
var textinSelected = document.getElementById("selectedText").innerHTML;
setInterval(function(){
if (window.screen.width << 1200) {
    document.getElementById("selectedText").innerHTML = "";
  }
else if (window.screen.width >> 1200){
    document.getElementById("selectedText").innerHTML = textinSelected;
  }
});
```

Here's the **Targeted Html** div:

```
 <div class="selected shadow-sm"><p id="selectedText">Catégories</p></div>
```

Comment: Note that [`<<`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Left_shift) and [`>>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift) are bitshift operators, not for comparing like `<` and `>`.

Comment: You have to listen to resize event on window but you should really use CSS media queries instead

Comment: What's the point in using `<<` `>>` in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window` resize event instead of `setInterval`. Also you should use `window.innerWidth` instead of `window.screen.width`. `window.innerWidth` return the viewport of the browser whereas `window.screen.width` return the screen size of the device (not the browser).

```js
var textinSelected = document.getElementById("selectedText").innerHTML;

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
    document.getElementById("selectedText").innerHTML = "";
  }
  else {
      document.getElementById("selectedText").innerHTML = textinSelected;
  }
});
```

```html
 <div class="selected shadow-sm"><p id="selectedText">Catégories</p></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

With CSS, what you preferebly should do.

```
#selectedText {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

  #selectedText {
    display: block;
  }

}
```

Or with JavaScript using [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

```
// Select the text element and value.
const selectedTextElement = document.querySelector('#selectedText');
const textValue = selectedTextElement.textContent;

// Create a media query.
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)');

// Toggle the text based on the media query.
const onMediaQueryChange = event => {
  if (event.matches) {
    selectedTextElement.textContent = textValue;
  } else {
    selectedTextElement.textContent = '';
  }
};

// Listen for changes whenever the screen size changes.
mediaQuery.addEventListener('change', onMediaQueryChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Javascript instead you can just use CSS and do this (And I think doing CSS is much better and healthy for your site):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="selected shadow-sm"><p id="selectedText">Catégories</p></div>
   <style>
:root {
 --blank: red;

 }

 @media (max-width: 1200px) {
   :root {
  
  --blank: white;
 
  
  }
 }

  #selectedText{
  color: var(--blank);
  }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```